# Parser matching QDoubleValidator exactly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I use a `QLineEdit` together with a `QDoubleValidator(bottom, top, decimals)` with its locale set to `QLocale("en")`. After checking for `QLineEdit::hasAcceptableInput()`, I try to parse the text. But unfortunately, even when the validation succeeds, parsing still can fail.

**Q:** What is the correct parser to use with `QDoubleValidator`, so that the validator actually filters out cases, that cannot be parsed?

*Example:* The text `8,0` is validated as a correct double (presumable because the comma is interpreted as digit seperator as I can enter multiple commas?) but `float("8,0")` as well as `loc.toDouble("8,0")` with `loc` being the `en` locale from above fails.

**Edit 1:**
Don't know if that's important, but I call `QValidator::setLocale()` before I call `QLineEdit::setValidator()`. Also, I (re-)use the same `QLocale` instance for all my validators as well as for my calls to `toDouble`. I don't modify the `QApplication`'s locale. `QLocale().name()` returns `de_DE`.

As explained in the comments, also `"8,0,0.0"` validates but fails to parse.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. After setting the validator to `QDoubleValidator(0, 100, 3)` (with `QLocale('en')`) and then setting the text to `"8,0"`, calling `hasAcceptableInput()` returns false. If I change the locale to `"de"`, it then returns true. So it all seems to work as expected.

Comment: That's odd. The same thing happens for `"8,0,0.0"` for me. `hasAcceptableInput()` returns true, but parsing fails. So I don't think, this a `en` vs `de` locale thing.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was about `en` vs `de`. I simply gave a basic example that works as expected. You need to provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: I don't know whether you saw my second comment, but your latest edit does not provide any useful information. Using my basic example, `"8,0,0.0"` will result in `hasAcceptableInput()` returning false for both locales (and it doesn't matter when the locale is set). So the problem must be caused by some other part of your code that you haven't yet shown. That is why you should always provide a [mcve]. My hunch is that your line-edit doesn't actually have any validator set (or at least not a `QDoubleValidator`).

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior anymore. Neither with an MWE, nor with my original application. Thanks, anyways.